# Negative margin-top behaves differently on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I am attempting to align two nested divs into one row by using negative margin-top, but the rendering on Firefox (FF) and Chrome is quite different. The following is the dummpy example on http://jsfiddle.net/2SK5t/

HTML

```
<div class='row_custom'>
    <div>Hello World</div>
</div>
<div class='row_custom'>
    <div class='row_2'>Hello World</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row_custom{
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}
.row_2{
    color:blue;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `display: table;` and they match up.